# Accessing element of a webpage using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to access the highlighted elements using a powershell script.[image]

I have tried the below code.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.navigate("http://jenkins-  ny.ciqdev.com/job/WebOperations/job/Tools/job/IIS%20Executing%20Requests/build?delay=0sec");
($ie.document.getElementsByName("servers")).value = "laser"
```

Can someone please correct me, where am i going wrong ?

HTML code for the page:

```
<div description="Which servers to run on" name="parameter">

<input name="name" value="Servers" type="hidden">

<select name="value" multiple="multiple" size="12">

<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
<option value="d">d</option>
<option value="e">e</option>

</select>

</div>

<div description="Which tiers to run on? Select none for all" name="parameter">

<input name="name" value="Tiers" type="hidden">

<select name="value" multiple="multiple" size="11">

<option value="f">CIQDotNetPool</option>
<option value="g">MachTPool</option>
<option value="h">CIQAppServerRootPool</option>
<option value="i">SessionlessAppPool</option>
<option value="j">CapitalIQ</option>

</select>

</div>
```

Comment: What's not working? What is "access"? Read? Write? Your sample tries to modify it to a value that doesn't exist in the list.

Comment: i want to select any value from both of the lists and then submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're trying to set the `value` of an element with `name="servers"`, but there are none. The `select`-element has `name="value"`.
2. You're setting the value and not the `SelectedIndex`-property/attribute.

Try this. Tested on a few samples (but failed on others). The hardest part was to get the corrent `select`-element.

```
#Find the select-element (you need something unique to find it)
$servers = $ie.Document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("select") | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'value' }

#Get index for the option you want to select
$option = $t.options | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq 'nitro.capiqinc.com' } | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Index

#Set value
$t.selectedIndex = $option
```

Comment: it is throwing an error saying "Property 'selectedIndex' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable." and by $t do you mean $servers ? Or is it a new variable.

Comment: "Property 'selectedIndex' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable." this is thrown against getElementsByTagName

Comment: Also, tag select is not unique, as we have another list which has same tag and same name =  "value"

Comment: then find the div (or something unique), search within it for the `Select`-item and continue. This is unique to your html and I can't see all it's code (which should have been a code-block wit fake server/domain-names and not a picture) so it's impossible for me to know what's unique or not. :-)

Comment: Hey, i have updated the question. I tried finding unique values but then there are two divs with same name . I want to select one value each from both the list and they are exctly same excepth the option value.

Comment: I ahve also tried GetElementsByTagName("div")  | where-object {$_.desciption -eq 'Which servers to run on'}..... it dint work.